# Display only form item from a CollectionType with error

Tags: symfony4

In a symfony 4.3 project I have a form with a CollectionType of `lineItems` for one of the form elements. The form works, complete with validation. The problem is that I can potentially have dozens of `lineItem` subforms, so if one `lineItem` fails validation I'd like to be able to display ONLY that failed item to the user (and just hide the others). The trouble is that I don't know how to identify which `lineItem` is failing so I can render only it (along with its error message).

My code is abbreviated to show the important portions only.

The main form:

```
class TreatmentFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('lineItems', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => LineItemFormType::class,
                'label' => 'Item',
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
            ])
            // other items omitted
            ;
    }
}
```

And my subform:

```
class LineItemFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('item')
            ->add('quantity')
            ->add('itemType');
    }
}
```

and my twig file where I want to access individual errors:

```
<div data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.lineItems.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {% if form.vars.valid %}
        // display data; code not shown
    {% else %}
        {% for line in form.lineItems %}
            // WHAT TO PUT HERE TO IDENTIFY ONLY THE FIELD WITH THE ERROR?
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

I do understand that when I submit the form and correct the errors that all fields will have to be rendered, but I'm not worried about that part, I just don't know how to pull out the `lineItem` that fails validation. I've tried lots of variations like `line.vars.errors`, but nothing gets me to the one failed element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking `line.{field_name}.vars.errors` is not empty for each field, then render what you need.

```
{% for line in form.lineItems %}
    {% if (line.item.vars.errors is not empty) or (line.quantity.vars.errors is not empty) or (line.itemType.vars.errors is not empty) %}
      {{ form_row(line.item) }}
      {{ form_row(line.quantity) }}
      {{ form_row(line.itemType) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or possibly check if `line.vars.valid` is false. I get the impression this is only present on the parent form but I'm not sure.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Comment: `line.vars.valid` seems to be present only on the parent form (if 1 item fails validation then `line.vars.valid` is false on all items in the loop). Your code works perfectly though.